Selenium Web Scraping SSL connection issue
I am trying to perform web scraping using Selenium. So, the website from which I want to scrape data requires authentication. So, my aim is to log into the website and scrape some user-related data.
So, first I am trying to log into the website for that, I am navigating to https://my.pitchbook.com/, and the website automatically redirects me to the below link:
https://loginprod.morningstar.com/loginstate=hKFo2SA1NkY0R2IwakMyYVFwTXNGSF8zampvSVRwU21abWhOZqFupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgX0NacFNHQTFfc29iOC1lckFEc3JGaFRaWHBNZkJ1Rk2jY2lk2SByWUMwT1V4SDRpV05jbXpPanVwQjh6UnN0dWtlZXZyUg&client=rYC0OUxH4iWNcmzOjupB8zRstukeevrR&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.pitchbook.com%2Fauth0%2Fcallback&source=bus0155&response_type=code
After redirecting me to the above link, a login page appears where I am trying to log into the website. However, I am getting errors:

I tried finding the solution to the error, I even wrote this code: chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')  # Disable SSL verification
Code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')  # Disable SSL verification

# Set up WebDriver service
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the initial page
driver.get("https://my.pitchbook.com/")

try:
    # Increase the wait time
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  

    # Wait for the URL to change after redirection
    wait.until(EC.url_changes("https://my.pitchbook.com/"))


    # Wait for the login form to load on the redirected page
    email_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "emailInput")))  
    password_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "passwordInput")))  
    login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "mds-button___ctrsi"))) 

    # Enter credentials (replace with actual credentials)
    email_element.send_keys("email")
    password_element.send_keys("password")
    login_button.click()

    # Wait for the login process to complete
    time.sleep(5)  # Adjust as necessary


    # Now you are authenticated, navigate to the desired page or interact with elements
    driver.get("https://my.pitchbook.com/dashboard/home")

    # Locate the element you want to interact with
    user_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "button__caption_a580497eb72793758caf95a9250e8342")))
    value = user_name.text

    print(value)

    # Wait before closing
    time.sleep(5)

finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

Your help will be appreciated! (I am newbie in Web Scraping and Selenium)

you should do this manually from a fresh profile to understand the flow of the login.  (you can just pause execution after going to the 1st URL) Chances are you need to provide credentials after the 1st redirect.  After doing that you'll be back at the "redirect_uri".  (You may need to enter credentials at the authorization server.... it seems to be expecting a cert, but obviously you won't have one since you've never logged in this browser session/profile)
